# 1 link for both iPhone and iPad app in Appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am creating an iPhone app. I would also like it to make it available for iPads. The problem is that the iPad version is very different(has different transitions between view controllers, more buttons). However, I would like only 1 link to the app in the app store that supports both iPhone and iPad. Can I upload 2 different builds for the same app(with the same name, but one is iPad version, the other is iphone) and than only have 1 app(with one link) in the app store for customers to download? For example, if I send a link to my app in App Store to let's say Gregory, I only send 1 link for both the iPad and iPhone version and not 2 like this:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myAppIPADVersion
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myAppIPHONEVersion

The main goal is to have 1 link to share like this https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myApp 
although I cannot upload one single build for iPad and iPhone, but 2 for each type of device.

Comment: No you can't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your app needs to be one universal build in order to appear as one app in the app store.

A universal app doesn't need to have the same interface or transitions. How you achieve this is up to you and depends on the volume of the differences.